# I am upgrading my Java project from Struts 2.3.15 to 2.3.34. What are the changes that I should do?

Tags: struts2, tiles, apache-tiles, tiles2

I am upgrading my project from Struts 2.3.15 to 2.3.34. What are the changes that I should do?

Comment: First read the release notes

Answer (score 0):

Read the needed release notes and migration guide from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Migration+Guide

Minor release in 2.3.x is not that problematic, but migrating to 2.5.x needs a little bit more planning.